# How to set a path in tcl like with cd in batch files?

Tags: batch-file, path, tcl, cd

I've been using Tcl language for a few days only, but I'm used to programming in other languages too; however, I can't find any reference anywhere as to how I could set the current directory or path as it can be done in batch language with the command cd.

I need this because I'm using Tcl to integrate several different programs. One of these has some apparent problems of recognizing the current path. If I execute it from a batch file, previously setting the path with cd and the folder where this program is, everything works fine.

However, if instead of using a batch file I use a basic Tcl script to call this program (I use exec), it doesn't seem to find the folder or files it needs, most likely because the relative paths it uses are mapped incorrectly.

Does anyone know an equivalent version of the batch cd for Tcl??

Thanks!!

Comment: Three essentially identical answers. _However,_ be aware that the current directory is rarely usefully set for a script that is double-clicked on (GUIs don't really have the concept of a current directory). Also, doing `cd` in a Tcl script _won't_ affect its caller, but it will affect any subprocesses created with `exec` (or `open`) in the future. These are general issues that are not special to Tcl in any way, because they're just how current directory handling works on all systems.

Answer (score 6):

you can just use the TCL commands cd and pwd. That should be all you need. See http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/cd.htm for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a trick I learned running tcl scripts on a windows computer.  Put {} around the windows path and you won't have to edit all the '\' to '/' to make it work. That way you can cut and paste from windows explorer.

cd {C:\paste\your\desired\windows\path\directly\here}

Answer (score 3):

the TCL for cd is (drum roll) [cd](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/cd.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Tcl also has `cd` command. - http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/cd.htm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I have understood now the problem I was having. I had originally tried to use the cd command as in standard batch language: I concluded that Tcl didn't had a cd command because the programs I'm integrating already had a cd command (overloading the built-in), and I got the results from this second version.

Unfortunately, modifying this second version to have a different name is not possible given the circumstances, so I will most likely have to alter the name of the built-in version of cd (does anybody know if this is even possible, or how?).

But again, thanks for the collaboration everyone!

Comment: You need to do `rename cd orig_cd` **before** you load the extension that creates its own cd command and hides the original one.  Then afterwards you can do `orig_cd some/directory`.